# Trouble getting div elements positioned at random X/Y

Tags: javascript

```
// T duplicates the selected element(s).
case 116:
    elementSel = document.querySelectorAll("div.selected");
    var elementClone,
    tmp = getBrowserWidth(),
    bww = tmp[0],
    bwh = tmp[1];

    for (i = 0; i < elementSel.length; i++) {
        elementClone = elementSel[i].cloneNode(true);
        elementClone.id = "boxID" + Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);
        elementClone.zIndex = "+1";

        var posx = getRandomInt(1, bww) - elementSel[i].offsetWidth;
        var posy = getRandomInt(1, bwh) - elementSel[i].offsetHeight;

        elementClone.style.left = posx + " px";
        elementClone.style.top = posy + " px";

        elementSel[i].appendChild(elementClone);
        elementSel[i].classList.toggle("selected");

        console.log("Created " + elementSel.length + " elements.");
    }
```

I am stuck doing a school assignment. I have tried to read similar questions but I do not get any further. The problem is `elementClone.style.left/.top` not getting assigned new values. Why?

Comment: what does `getBrowserWidth()` do and return. Try placing a `debugger` statement before `var posx = getRandomInt(1, bww)` or add `console.log()` messages throughout the code and check your browser console to debug it. Are `posx` and `posy` set to new values as expected? What is the value of `tmp` . Is the code even reaching `case 116`?

Comment: What does the `getRandomInt` function look like?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, `posx` and `posy` are set to new values. I have tried with `console.log()`.

Comment: @wackozacko, `function getRandomInt(min, max) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); }`

Comment: @AnttiKeränen Ok, that's not the problem then. Best option is to add some `console.log()` statements in. If posx and posy do change values, then maybe it's a css thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The problem was `" px"`. Crappé!

Answer (score 0):

Related answer:
It is working for me, may be the reason is you need to change the `position` and `float` attributes.